# EXCEL 2007: Calculate a working average, which skips blanks

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

OK So here's a scren grab of my EXCEL document.

I need it to create an average from each test taken, however it needs to skip any blank cells. So if a pupil only takes 4 of 6 tests, it will only calculate 4 tests not all 6. ACROSS THE PAGE NOT DOWN!

CURRENTLY USING: =AVERAGE(D3,F3,H3,J3,L3,N3,P3)

What code should I use? And why?

I keep seeing `<>""` when I  google for it but i have no idea what this means, other than equal to nothing.

[image]

Comment: What you've tried already? What was the result? What would be the correct result? ..

Comment: If I'm not wrong you are calculating Grade but not the Average or you have a logical Formula If with Average. Better you edit the question and add the Formula currently you have used.

Comment: UPDATED: Im calculating the average Mark not Grade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `P7 Waves` as an example, he has the values:

```
0
32
25
36
17
38
blank
blank
21
blank
blank
31
32
```

If I am correct, you want the average of these values while ignoring the `blank` values. So, `(0+32+25+36+17+38+21+31+32)/9 = 25.7778`

In this case, use the following formula...

```
=AVERAGE(B1:B14)
```

Where `B1` is the first of you values and `B14` is the last, adjust as needed. The `AVERAGE()` function ignores blank values (at least in Excel 2017/365).

**EDIT**

The `AVERAGE()` function works across too. Simply type `AVERAGE(` and then select your range, example `AVERAGE(A1:R1)` this will sum the numbers in `A1` `B1` and so on then divide by the number of numbers it found. It ignores none number content (letters and blanks).

Here is an example, this is for your first `G` grade.

[image: Example]

Comment: I'm trying to go across not down

Comment: I edited my comment, the same formula works both horizontally and vertically.